# Meaning of Total errors on result of Clamav scan

Tags: clamav

I scanned my Ubuntu computer using Clamav the following are the results

```
Known viruses: 2288150
Engine version: 0.97.8
Scanned directories: 55215
Scanned files: 283662
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 18736
Data scanned: 16464.40 MB
Data read: 30027.11 MB (ratio 0.55:1)
Time: 4558.179 sec (75 m 58 s)
```

My Question is what are total errors and I should I do some thing to remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this [Clamav faq](http://www.clamxav.com/faq.php#Q21)  question #21. No need to sweat.

> These "errors" are not actually errors but are usually files you don't
>   have read access to. They may belong to another user or to the System.
>   Either way they probably aren't anything to be concerned about.

Comment: If I see this error, does this mean my Scan is not running via Root user?

Comment: What if I'm the only use on the system, have run clamscan as sudo, and have 16343 errors!?